# filtering AWT textfield input texts

Tags: java, awt, textfield

In jtextfield, One can restrict the inputs of an jtextfield by overriding the insertString method of document.
How can i do these in awt textfield?
How can i filter the inputs of an awt textfield?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> One can restrict the inputs of an jtextfield by overriding the
>   insertString method of document.

- not possible for `AWT TextField`, you can to add [DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) only to [Swing JTextComponents](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html)

> jtextfield by overriding the insertString method of document.

- maybe you need to use `DocumentFilter` for `Swing JTextComponent`s

> How can i do these in awt textfield? How can i filter the inputs of an
>   awt textfield?

- for `AWT TextField` you can use

  1. [TextListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/TextListener.html)
  2. [KeyListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html)
  3. [listening from AWTEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/AWTEvent.html)